# How to check workbook structure and content?

Tags: excel

I have some excel workbook which I need to check they comply with some criteria in terms of structure (tabs, columns header) and content (columns format and value). Also, I would need to know for each the status of the checks performed (failed or passed).

How should I do this ?

Comment: This is a very open question.  You just have to do the work.  Read up on VBA and then go from there.  There is no simple solution.

Comment: As Skin said, you will need to implment a VBA Macro for such a job.

Comment: You might start with Looping thru all workbooks in a folder, opening each one..   See  url https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/open-close-workbook/    and then find paragraph  "Open All Excel Workbooks in a Folder".  Then when it is open, perform some of the criteria.  And close that workbook before going on to the next.  Do you want the audit results to appear in a new/separate spreadsheet?